# Expanded dropdown overlapping existing items/text

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a dropdown, when I expand it, it's item and existing controls are getting mixed. I want to hide bg items completely and Dropdown going inside another `divs`. This is my code

dropdown.component.css

```css
    .parent {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      line-height: 30px;
      background-color: #4FA0D8;
      min-width: 18em;
    }
    
    .parent a {
      margin: 10px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .parent.active>span>ul {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .child {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .child li {
      background-color: #E4EFF7;
      line-height: 30px;
      border-bottom: #CCC 1px solid;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .child li a {
      color: #000000;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0px;
      min-width: 18em;
    }
    
    ul ul ul {
      left: 100%;
      top: 0;
      margin-left: 1px;
    }
    
    li:hover {
      background-color: #95B4CA;
    }
    
    .expand {
      font-size: 12px;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
```

dropdowncomponenet.html file

```html
    <ul #dropdown [ngClass]="isChild ? 'child' : ''">
        <li class="parent" *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="open(item)" [ngClass]="item.isOpen ? 'active' : ''">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">{{item.name}}</a>
            <span class="expand" *ngIf="item.children.length > 0">&nbsp;&nbsp;&#10095;</span>
            <span dropdown *ngIf="item.children.length > 0 && item.isOpen" [items]="item.children" isChild="true"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Screenshot before and after expanding dropdown. Sorry for not providing images clear

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has bee fixed by adding two atribute in css style `.parent`

```
position: relative;
z-index: 10000;
```